# My MPI fortran code gives different results for large integers

Tags: variables, integer, fortran, mpi

I am *very* new to MPI programming (like 3 days old). I am now dealing with `MPI_ALLREDUCE` and `MPI_REDUCE`.
The code below takes a value `n` and the task of every process is to add 1 to the variable `mypartialsum`  for `n/num_procs` times, where `num_procs` is the number of processes. After the reduction the values of `mypartialsum` are gathered in `sum` and the final result is `sum=n`.
The code seems to work fine if `n<1d10`, but for `n>=1d10` I get the wrong result.
For example, if I run the code with `n=1d10` the value of sum is `1410065408`, while it is correct for `n=1d9`. What I am missing? I suspect it could be something with the kind of the variables, but after looking on the internet it is not clear to me what the problem is.

```
program test
      use mpi
      IMPLICIT NONE
      !include 'mpif.h'
      integer:: ierr, num_procs, my_id, status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE), sender(MPI_STATUS_SIZE), root, rank
      integer:: i!, n 
      integer, parameter :: MyLongIntType = selected_int_kind (12)
      integer(kind=MyLongIntType):: n
      !real:: sum=0., partialsum=0., mypartialsum=0.
      integer(kind=MyLongIntType):: sum=0, partialsum=0, mypartialsum=0
      real:: starttime, endtime
      root=0

      call MPI_INIT ( ierr )
      call MPI_COMM_RANK (MPI_COMM_WORLD, my_id, ierr)
      call MPI_COMM_SIZE (MPI_COMM_WORLD, num_procs, ierr)
      starttime = MPI_WTIME()
      if (my_id .eq. root) then 
            print*, "Running in process 0."
            print*, "total numeber of process is", num_procs
            n=int8(1d10)!1000000000
      endif
      
      call MPI_BCAST(n, 1, MPI_INTEGER, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
      !print*, "running process", my_id
      mypartialsum=0.
      do i = my_id+1, n, num_procs
            mypartialsum=mypartialsum+int(1)
      enddo 
      partialsum=mypartialsum
      print*, "Running process", my_id, "Partial sum is ", partialsum
      call MPI_REDUCE(partialsum, sum, 1, MPI_INTEGER, MPI_SUM, ROOT, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
      !call MPI_ALLREDUCE(partialsum, sum, 1, MPI_INTEGER, MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)

      endtime = MPI_WTIME()
      if (my_id .eq. 0) then
       print*, "sum is", sum, "time spent processing",  endtime-starttime
!      else if (my_id .gt. 0) then 
!       print*, "sum on process", my_id, "is", sum , "time spent processing is", endtime-starttime
      endif
     
     
      call MPI_FINALIZE ( ierr )
     

end program
```

Comment: Rather than `n=int8(1d10)` which uses a non-standard function better is `n=1000000000_MyLongIntType`

Comment: Partial sum might mean you should use MPI_Scan instead. I dunno.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are telling `MPI_Reduce` that the type being summed is `MPI_INTEGER`. However, `MPI_INTEGER` corresponds to the default integer kind in Fortran. You have to provide the correct MPI type that corresponds to the `selected_int_kind (12)` type.

One of the possible ways, specifically for kinds resulting from `selected_integer_kind` is the `MPI_Type_create_f90_integer(r, newtype, ierror)` subroutine.

So something like `call MPI_Type_create_f90_integer(12, MyLongIntMPIType, ierror)`.

There are other alternatives, like using fixed memory storage kinds like `integer(int64)` and the `MPI_INTEGER8` MPI type originally developed for the non-standard `integer*8`.

See also [Additional Support for Fortran Numeric Intrinsic Types](https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report/node416.htm)

It also contains this important advice to users:

> The datatypes returned by the above functions are predefined
> datatypes. They cannot be freed; they do not need to be committed;
> they can be used with predefined reduction operations.

which makes it simple to use the returned type in `MPI_Reduce()` with `MPI_SUM`.